# Remove random entry until collection is empty

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, types, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty sure this is something basic but for some reason I just can't seem to get it work. First I'm not sure which Collection Type I should be using. I'm using C# for my Unity game and I'd like to store info like this:

```
#  Name  Number Value
1  Jim   15
2  Bob   21
3  Tim   31
4  Ron   26
```

Numbers 1-4 would be indexes so if I removed entry #3 with Tim, the table would look like:

```
#  Name  Number Value
1  Jim   15
2  Bob   21
3  Ron   26
```

I assume I should be using Dictionaries and that's what I tried. What I want to do with my code is to pick a random element, print it and then remove it. Rinse and repeat until the list is empty.

This is what I've been using for my code:

```
Dictionary<String, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, int> ();
void Start()
{
  myDictionary.Add ("Jim", 15);
  myDictionary.Add ("Bob", 21);
  myDictionary.Add ("Tim", 31);
  myDictionary.Add ("Ron", 26);
}

void Update()
{
  int totalEntries = myDictionary.Count;
  int randNumber = Random.Range(1,totalEntries);
  print(myDictionary[randNumber]);
  myDictionary.Remove(randNumber);
}
```

It's not working. I've seen some suggestions about using RemoveAt or using HashTable but I haven't been able to get those working either. RemoveAt for some reason isn't recognized as a command and HashTable just kind of had the same issue. I am using "using System.Collections.Generic;" btw so that's not the problem. I'd like to mention that I'm pretty new to C# so what would help me the most would be actual working code that I can then edit to fit my game.

Comment: What exactly means "it's not working"?

Comment: Side note: Indexing in C# starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: dictionary indexing is indexing on a key, which is a string ( the name of the person)

Comment: Alright, so if I can't index by row number (which would get updated automatically when elements are added/removed) what should I use instead of Dictionaries? Are there other Collection Types that can hold multiple variables per row? Or I guess I could even just use two of the same Collection Type and store data that way. In any case, what Collection Type should I use in order to be able to remove an entry by its position/row. So basically "Remove entry in position/row number 4" as an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary would not be ideal in this case.
I'd use a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of [Tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a custom class).

```
List<Tuple<int, String, int>> myItems = new List<Tuple<int, String, int>>();
void Start()
{
  myItems.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "Jim", 15));
  myItems.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "Bob", 21));
  myItems.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "Tim", 31));
  myItems.Add(Tuple.Create(4, "Ron", 26));
}
```

Now there are a couple of ways to identify the object you wish to remove. First your initial approach (by index in the list):

```
void Update()
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  var randNumber = rnd.Next(0, myItem.Count);
  myItems.Remove(myItems.ElementAt(randNumber));
}
```

Then by the actual value of the object:

```
void Update2()
{
  var minValue = myItems.Min(i => i.Item1);       // Gets the minimum value in first column (so to speak);
  var maxValue = myItems.Max(i => i.Item1);       // Gets the maximum value.
  var rnd = new Random();
  var randNumber = rnd.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);  // maximum value in Random.Next is exclusive.
  var myObject = myItems.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Item1 == randNumber);
  if (myObject != null)
    myItems.Remove(myObject);
}
```

Which method you prefer is up to you and the requirements to solve the task. You might prefer by index but on the other hand you might prefer removing by value.

The drawback by the second method is that you might not remove an object at all when the random value is already removed.

Comment: any chance you could help me get this in C# instead of java?

Comment: My bad. For some reason inside the Start() function, myItems.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "Jim", 15));  Tuple and Create are written in red as if they're incorrect, any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: You might be using a .NET Framework version less than 4. Tuple was introduced in version 4. In that case I'd use a custom class.

Comment: hmm I'm just using Unity 5 which was just released a few days ago... I'll try and update my .NET Framework though, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need `ElementAt()` in case of `IList<T>` where you can use *indexer*.

Comment: @abatishchev: You're correct. It is however usefull when using a **collection** that doesn't have an **indexer**. Since the OP didn't know which type of collection to use, I supplied the more generic **ElementAt** instead. But as you say an indexer is preferred in this case where I use a **List**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;

var r = new Random();
var i = r.Next(0, dic.Count);
var e = dic.ElementAt(i)
dic.Remove(e);
```

Comment: Is that java? (I'm using c#)

Comment: @srefanpic: you can access dictionary by index using the extension method `ElementAt()` after including the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0):

create an array with the same length, and out in each cell a number 1 to N. and shuffle the array. then delete each row by index

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding this link: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Choosing_the_right_collection_type

And have been able to solve my issue with ArrayLists. This is the part of the link that really helped me:

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();    // declaration
myArrayList.Add(anItem);                    // add an item to the end of the array
myArrayList[i] = newValue;                  // change the value stored at position i
TheType thisItem = (TheType) myArray[i];    // retrieve an item from position i
myArray.RemoveAt(i);                        // remove an item from position i
var howBig = myArray.Count;                 // get the number of items in the ArrayList
```

Thanks everyone for all the sugestions!

Comment: Don't use non-generic `ArrayList`, ever. Always use generic `List<T>` instead